# Javascript prompt and submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a value from JavaScript prompt and pass it to input for finally submit it

**HTML**

```
<form id="createdirForm"><input type="text" name="" id="createdir"/><form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createdir() {
    var newdirname;
    newdirname = prompt('Please input the directory name:', '');
    if (!newdirname) return;
    $('createdir').newdirname.value = newdirname;
    $('createdirForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: so? what is the problem? what have you tried. What is the thought process behind it

Comment: is not submitting when i enter new name @Vatsal

Comment: doesn't the form require an ACTION property for it to do anything when submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you're not calling the selector in your jQuery properly.

You might want to take a look at the [jQuery Selector Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm).

Now to fix your problem, since you want to get the input and the form by the `id` attribute, just like in CSS, you need to use the `hashtag (#)` symbol.

So you would do:

```
$('#createdir').val(newdirname);
$('#createdirForm').submit();
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/vm4ah1L3/1/

Just a side note, you might want to add a name to your html input otherwise when you submit it to your PHP, you won't be able to retrieve the value since the name attribute is empty.

```
<input type="text" name="dirName" id="createdir">
```

And in your case, since you're declaring the variable `newdirname` and assign it right after, you could simply do the assignation in one line:

```
var newdirname = prompt("Please input a directory name: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your jQuery selector is wrong. Try

```
$('#createdir').val(newdirname);
$('#createdirForm').submit();
```

jQuery uses the css selector logic, therefore to select an element by id you need to put the `#` before the selector name.

Also, to add a value to an input, you need to use `val(param)` with your value replaced in the param.

Answer (score 0):

You have some **typo** and have forgotten to add `#`. And the function is not executed.

**HTML**

```
<form id="createdirForm">
    <input type="text" name="dir" id="createdir" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createdir() {
    var newdirname;
    newdirname = prompt('Please input the directory name:', '');
    if (!newdirname) return;
    $('#createdir').value = newdirname;
    $('#createdirForm').submit();
}

createdir();
```

Comment: is submitting but the dir name is empty i try to output it but nothing show `<?php if(isset($_POST['dir'])){echo $_POST['dir'];}?>`

Comment: You have to set a name for the `<input>`.